# Can I store a helm chart in OpenShift and make use of it?

Tags: openshift, kubernetes-helm

I have uploaded a helm chart as an OCI compliant container to Openshift. However, I can't add the openshift registry as a helm repo, or find another way to persuade helm to use the "imagestream" as a source to install.

```
export HELM_EXPERIMENTAL_OCI=1
oc whoami --show-token | helm registry login my-cluster.com -u $(oc whoami) --password-stdin
helm create mychart
cd mychart/
helm chart save . my-cluster.com/$(oc project -q)/mychart:latest
helm chart push my-cluster.com/$(oc project -q)/mychart:latest
```

And that creates a "mychart" imagestream with a `dockerImageManifestMediaType: application/vnd.oci.image.manifest.v1+json` 
But whenever I try to add my-cluster.com as a repo or install any other way, it just gives me a 404 error :

```
helm install --username $(oc whoami) --password $(oc whoami --show-token) --repo https://my-cluster.com/$(oc project -q) mychart chart
Error: looks like "https://my-cluster.com/project" is not a valid chart repository or cannot be reached: failed to fetch https://my-cluster.com/project/index.yaml : 404 Not Found
```

Would it require the registry to do something "clever" to create the index.yaml which is missing in Openshift registry?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out you need to do :

```
helm chart pull registry/mychart:tag
helm chart export registry/mychart:tag .
```

So that your chart is in the current directory. And then you can :

```
helm install release mychart
```

There is a PR for future versions of helm to do a install of something like oci://registry/mychart:tag saving a few steps. I suppose this is the difference between registry and repository that was causing me problems.

Absolutely no need for chartmuseum or other third party apps.

Comment: https://github.com/helm/helm/pull/9782 with details of the new oci:// syntax

Answer (score 0):

a helm chart is not the same as an OCI compliant container!
a helm chart basically is a compressed directory which a specified layout.

However, it is possible to host a chartmuseum on openshift, push your charts to said chartmuseum and then add it as a helm repository.

see the [chartmuseum github repository](https://github.com/helm/chartmuseum) for more information on how to host your own chartmuseum and [this tutorial](https://docs.bitnami.com/tutorials/create-your-first-helm-chart/) on how the chart should look like exactly and how to push it to your hosted chartmuseum.

Comment: Sorry, not container. "Artifact". I'd rather not be installing something I need to manage and get approved and figure out authentication for, etc etc. When I could just drop it in the existing registry and grant permission to another namespace (which I already did for reading container images). Corporate policy is tough on new apps, compared to what's already there. If it worked, would make my life much easier. If it doesn't : the charts are staying in our corporate git repo.

Comment: Helm charts are oci artifacts : https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/containers/oci-artifact-support-in-amazon-ecr/

Comment: Actually just found that redhat have a locally deployable version of quay.io that would do it, and being from redhat, easier to gain approval than chartmusuem. https://www.openshift.com/blog/quay-oci-artifact-support-for-helm-charts